# Is $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}xe^{-n^{2}x}$ convergent on specified intervals?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}xe^{-n^{2}x}, \ x \geq 0$ convergent uniformly on specified intervals?

Comment: I suppose that you could also compare $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}xe^{-n^{2}x} \lt \int_1^{\infty}xe^{-n^{2}x}dn=\frac{\sqrt{\pi x}}{2}  \space \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

$$f_n(x)=xe^{-n^2x}$$
then we have

$$f_n'(x)=e^{-n^2x}(1-n^2x)=0\iff x=\frac1{n^2}$$
so we see easily that
$$||f_n||_\infty=f_n\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)=\frac{e^{-1}}{n^2}$$
so the Riemann series $\sum_{n\ge1}||f_n||_\infty$ is convergent and then the given series is uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty)$.